# How to solve these two integrals after substitution

Tags: improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(u^2+y_p-y_s)\right]\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\beta}(u-\sqrt{y_s})^2\right]}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(u^2+y_p-y_s)}}\,u\,du,
$$
where $\beta,\,x_s,\,y_p$ and $y_s$ are constants and there is no relation between them. I change from $u$ to $t=\frac{u-\sqrt{y_s}}{\sqrt{\beta}}$ and I obtain these two integrals which are quite similar:
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{y_s}{\beta}}}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(\beta(t+\sqrt{y_s})^2+y_p-y_s)-t^2\right]}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(\beta(t+\sqrt{y_s})^2+y_p-y_s)}}\,t \,dt
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{y_s}{\beta}}}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(\beta(t+\sqrt{y_s})^2+y_p-y_s)-t^2\right]}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta(x_s^2-1)}(\beta(t+\sqrt{y_s})^2+y_p-y_s)}}\, dt
$$
but I don't know how to carry out the integration after performing the substitution. How can I compute the integrals?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you suspect that this has a nice closed form?

Comment: What **exactly** is the difference between the last two integrals? They both look identical to me...and they both undoable and ugly.

Comment: The fact that the integral involves polynoms and exponentials; but maybe the integral has no solution in terms of mathematical functions.

Comment: The first integral has a t multiplying the integrand in the second @DonAntonio

Comment: Wow, was that hidden or what! Thanks